Most performant way to left pad a string in C++ with zeros?
I have an unsigned int num_count and a for loop with unsigned int current. I need to create a string of current with leading zeros up to num_count.
I checked different resources online and on StackOverflow as well. The ones that I have found that can be done with more or less older C++ standard are the following ones:
std::string pad1(unsigned int digits, unsigned long num)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(digits) << std::setfill('0') << num;
    return ss.str();
}

std::string pad2(unsigned int digits, unsigned long num)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string(num);
    return std::string(digits - s.length(), '0').append(s);
}

std::string pad3(unsigned int digits, unsigned long num)
{
    std::string s = std::to_string(num);
    return s.insert(0, digits - s.length(), '0');
}

I checked the Release disaembly (I hope that I checked all the right boxes) and was wondering what is the best one of those. To my suprise the line count of the dissembly per function more or less are:

pad1: 143 lines
pad2: 230 lines
pad3: 57 lines

I expected pad2 to be the shortest and probably the fastest one, but if I just count the instructions pad3 is way better than the others.
This is the assembly I got from the assembly view in Visual Studio: https://gist.github.com/cwansart/1f01c424dbb17af9623cdaa34d070b09
Can somebody explain this or did I just made errors when generating the assembly?
I want to know which one would be generally preferable when it comes to performance. I do not aim or any specific compiler, I just used Visual Studio now, at work I use gcc. For now i can only use up to C++11.
I get a file with a size of 500 mb but I can only work with 100 mb at a time. In that case I need to split them. In order to keep them together I create IDs for them with the format <fileName>-<count>. Count is the number that will be filled with zeros. Digits depends on how many blocks I will have, here it is 500/100=5, so 1 digits. With a 1000 mb file it would be 1000/100=10, so 2 digits.

First you need to define “best” since only you know your requirements. Performance? Memory usage? Allocation count? Something else? Only with this one compiler or in general?

Best as in good performance/allocation count ratio. More allocations will probably cause worse performance. The question is general, I just happen to have Visual Studio here. I have not yet checked the assembly of gcc.

Readability/Maintainability/Portability? All could be performance indicators. The best way for you is to understand your use case, its memory usage. And then MEASURE on your system using a profiler. And then one by one remove your systems bottleneck and optimize your systems specific properties. We cannot do that (remotely) for you.

Also assembly on its own is not a good way to judge anything. More instructions with less branches are usually even faster. It all depends on how the CPU can pipeline and prefetch data into caches/registers

I would put my money on #3, from the fact that it only creates one string. If the padding is not surprisingly large, the result will fit in the SSO buffer, and you have no heap allocation.

@PepijnKramer frankly, I find neither of those C++ variants readable compared to printf. But I was curious of those three. Portability is very important but I was not aware that it would be any issue here. Mainly I want know which one will perform best. Your argument about instructions with less branches is something I did not think about. That's a good point.

@BoP assumptions :) Using a static buffer could also work.... again nothing we can say without knowing the actual data

@BoP the padding will be at most 10 or maybe up to 20 in extremely rare cases.

Have you tried using std::format yet? Maybe that's performant enough

@PepijnKramer I did not try std::format yet since we're struck with C++11 for now. I really like the syntax and that would be my favorite choice.

if possible do not pad anything but only add the zeros when you print it (or is output in any other way).

Not sure but it seems : https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html is C++ compatible

I added some additional info about what I am padding. I did not know that this would be of help. Here is the text: I get a file with a size of 500 mb but I can only work with 100 mb at a time. In that case I need to split them. In order to keep them together I create IDs for them with the format <fileName>-<count>. Count is the number that will be filled with zeros. Digits depends on how many blocks I will have, here it is 500/100=5, so 1 digits. With a 1000 mb file it would be 1000/100=10, so 2 digits.

@PepijnKramer fmt was recommended by a friend too, but I wanted to avoid new dependencies.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai that is an interesting way. Maybe that would be sufficient and even faster

fmt should work as a header file only lib

this is about padding file names with either 1 or 2 zeros?!? I am certain that any computation you do with the data from the files will take more time than padding the file names. Anyhow, merely number of instructions is no good measure for performance. If you do care about performance you need to measure the performance.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Thats why I say profile the whole system (code + data).  So it is known that padding is really a bottleneck or not ;)

@463035818_is_not_an_ai no, it is more like this: file.txt-01, file.txt-02, ..., file.txt-10, file.txt-11 and so on. The only requirement is that all names including the count have the same length. That is why I am padding.

@PepijnKramer I don't think that performance matters in my case. Neither of those operations are slower than the following network requests. I was just courios what the benefits of those possible options are. And as you may guess I am not as knowledgable in this area, but I was interested.

exactly.  file.txt-01, file.txt-02, ..., file.txt-10, file.txt-11 means you are padding 1 zero at most. You do this once per file, how much data do you process per file? What fraction of the runtime is taken by adding that one zero? This is the question you need to answer for your self. If it is a significant fraction of the total runtime then you know that improving that part will impact the runtime of the whole program. I doubt it.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai When there are really big files the padding might be 10 digits or more. But that will probably not happen often. My guess is that it will be around 1-4 digits for the next years.
I agree that this overall probably does not matter. I asked because I was courious which way could be generally the best overall option.

btw knowing what can be done and what to use as the default is not necessarily premature optimization (if you dont know the term, search for it), nevertheless the way to learn something about performance in this case is to measure. Suppose someone told you "method 1 is the fastest, I know that for sure", what would that gain you? How would you know they are wrong or right? You would need to measure.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I agree. The situation was that I implemented it using stringstream but when I searched for something different I came across the inser variant. I just tested those three running in a loop with 999999 iterations, digits set to 8, num set to 123. pad1: 561 ms, pad2: 27 ms and pad3: 21 ms. I will test further. Thanks so far for the input!

fewer instructions doesn't necessarily relate to better performance: https://quick-bench.com/q/Iu0Z-sEyl8jZO2eFLer88gk0pjw

To be honest with you, padding zeros at the beginning of a string and being concerned over the performance is almost akin to dropping a teaspoon of salt into the Amazon River and hoping an ecological disaster hasn't happened.

Firstly, note that "best" or "fastest" are often unclear and difficult to measure. The amount of assembly output doesn't necessarily tell you what will perform best.
That being said, when working with types such as std::string, the one thing to avoid is allocations.
Calls to the global operator new are synchronized, and may be extremely expensive, depending on how they obtain memory from the operating system.
Knowing that the cost of allocations is likely the performance bottleneck, we should try to have at most one.
std::to_string makes that difficult, as it may allocate just barely enough memory to fit the string contents, but not enough to fit the additional padding, resulting in two allocations, possibly.
Knowing this, we can write the following:
// note: for convenience, the amount of padding is usually given as the minimum width of
//       the string, not as the amount of additional digits
std::string pad(unsigned int x, std::size_t num)
{
    // assuming a 32-bit unsigned int ...
    constexpr int max_digits = 10;
    char result[max_digits];

    // to_chars should be the fastest standard library routine to stringify integers
    std::to_chars_result r = std::to_chars(std::begin(result), std::end(result), x);
    // determine the actual amount of decimal digits
    std::size_t digits = r.ptr - result;

    std::string s;
    // resize_and_overwrite is a C++23 feature; you could do something similar by resizing
    // the string with '0' as filling first to achieve the padding, then memcpying
    // the digits into the string, as shown
    s.resize_and_overwrite(std::max(digits, num), [&](char* buffer, std::size_t size) {
        if (num > digits) {
            std::memset(buffer, '0', num - digits);
            // advance the buffer pointer so that the digits get copied into
            // the right place
            buffer += num - digits;
        }
        std::memcpy(buffer, result, digits);
    });

    return s;
}

I don't claim that this is the absolute fastest method, but it should be reasonably fast.
As with any performance-critical code, you should benchmark to verify what's actually fast.
Your worries about performance are likely unwarranted, since the cost of I/O (creating files) will likely dominate, not the cost of making some strings.
If you're creating only five strings, this should not show up on the radar at all.
